# Disjointness of allocated memory blocks?

Tags: c++14, specifications

It was my impression that a call to the allocation function will result in a pointer to the start of a memory block (A) such that all subsequent calls allocate a block of memory disjoint from A. But I yet to find that requirement (or a requirement implicating this) in the C++14 specification (ISO/IEC 14882:2014(E)), specifically § 3.7.4.1.

**Question:** Is it part of the specification, and if so where can I find it?

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to verify it's impossible for two objects to be dynamically allocated over the same memory?

Comment: @GManNickG yes (based on the specification)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in [basic.stc.dynamic.allocation]/2: the requirements on "allocation functions":

> Furthermore, for the library allocation functions in [new.delete.single] and [new.delete.array], `p0` shall represent the address of a block of storage disjoint from the storage for any other object accessible to the caller.

Note that this is from N4659, a C++17 draft. The N4140 draft document for C++14 does not contain this; it was added due to a defect resolution for [CWG issue 1338](http://wg21.link/cwg1338).